# flashlike javascript framework or simple html5 solution

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, html

I am kind of new to javascript/html5. normally I would do that kind of stuff inside flash/as3. but since the iPad doesn't support that I need to switch the horse...

I want to build a website where words are floating in position and size and if the mouse comes over one word it should draw some lines to all the other words. are there any frameworks one could use? the whole should look like a tag cloud with lines between the tags.

Comment: yes, stumpled over Raphael and EaselJS, too. good frameworks. but not that easy to learn, right? @Hardik: AIR is based on AS3 and uses the flashplayer, so that's no option... it is also standalone-based, not browser-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a good JS replacement for Flash. It's a vector graphics based library.

Comment: I love Raphael -- it's awesome, and it even supports older versions of IE, thanks to some clever conversion between SVG and VML. However it has one major issue: The Android browser doesn't support SVG (or VML), and so Raphael drawings won't work in Android. This may or may not be an issue for you, but since you specifically mentioned the iPad, I have to assume that you're interested in solutions that work for other mobile devices as well. If you need to work on Android, you may find a Canvas-based soltion is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [EaselJs](https://github.com/gskinner/EaselJS) from Grant Skinner. The approach he used is similar to Flash display list and timeline.

Here are some example:
https://github.com/mikechambers/ExamplesByMesh/tree/master/HTML5/EaselJS/follow
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/01/24/easeljs-example-follow-drone/
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/12/easel-js-simplifies-working-with-canvas-in-html5.html

A game Grant did:
http://www.pirateslovedaisies.com/